# animation: pulse размер блока

Tags: css

Всем привет нужно что бы блок плавно увеличивался и уменьшался нашел свойство: animation: animation: pulse 2s infinite; однако рамер блока при увеличении слишмком велик - как сделать что бы блок уменьшался и увеличивался гораздо меньше чем стоит по умолчанию? заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужны объяснения спрашивайте ..

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffbb;
}

body:hover .item {
  animation: pulse 0.68s ease;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо за оперативный ответ - нужна анимация которую можно зациклить и при этом что бы объект изначально находился в уменьшенном состоянии, а потом трансформировался в свой реальный размер? @MaximLensky